# How can I create organization definition?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Hyper ledger fabric official documents don't provide no setup manual.
How to create organization definition??

Document just refers to how to create user and MSP.

> Create an organization definition
>   Like peers, all orderers must belong to an organization that must be created before the orderer itself is created. This organization has a definition encapsulated by a Membership Service Provider (MSP) that is created by a Certificate Authority (CA) dedicated to creating the certificates and MSP for the organization.
>
> For information about creating a CA and using it to create users and an MSP, check out the Fabric CA user’s guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are a beginner in Hypelredger fabric development then I recommend you to start **IBM Blockchain Platform VS Code extension**. It will provide a local fabric environment to create, test and deploy a fabric smart contract. Also generate 1 peer, 1 orderer, 1 CA service under VS code environment.

Here is a [link](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/blockchain?topic=blockchain-develop-vscode) to start development with VS code extension.

Hope it will help you:)